# Create lags using adjacent column in a data.frame

Tags: r, time-series, replace, bigdata

I have a large dataset that looks like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
id <- c(3,3,3,5,5,7)
amount <- c(24,48,60,84,96,175)
start <- as.Date(c("2006-01-01","2009-12-09","2010-01-01","2006-04-24", "2009-12-09","2009-05-01"))
end <- as.Date(c("2010-01-01","2010-01-01","2010-01-01","2009-12-09","2009-12-09", "2009-05-01"))               
noise <-rnorm(6)
test <- data.frame(id,amount,start,end,noise)            

  id amount      start        end      noise
   3     24 2006-01-01 2010-01-01  0.4978505
   3     48 2009-12-09 2010-01-01 -1.9666172
   3     60 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  0.7013559
   5     84 2006-04-24 2009-12-09 -0.4727914
   5     96 2009-12-09 2009-12-09 -1.0678237
   7    175 2009-05-01 2009-05-01 -0.2179749
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
  id amount      start        end      noise   switch
   3     24 2006-01-01 2009-12-09  0.4978505        0
   3     48 2009-12-09 2010-01-01 -1.9666172        1
   3     60 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  0.7013559        2
   5     84 2006-04-24 2009-12-09 -0.4727914        0 
   5     96 2009-12-09 2009-12-09 -1.0678237        1
   7    175 2009-05-01 2009-05-01 -0.2179749        0
```

That is, I would like to lag the values of start and replace the values of end with them, by ID. Second, I would like to create a new variable called 'switch' that counts how many times the 'amount' changes on the id with the first observation being == 0 for the initial condition. I have tried using `ts()` to make the lags, which does what I want in principle, though it produces a ts object rather than a Date:

```
       out <- cbind(as.ts(test$start),lag(test$start))
       colnames(out) <- c("start","end")
       cbind(as.ts(test$start),lag(test$start))

         as.ts(test$start) lag(test$start)
            NA           13149
          13149           14587
          14587           14610
          14610           13262
          13262           14587
          14587           14365
          14365              NA
```

So the `lag(test$start)` column is what my end should look like, but applied over the id variable. So I try to vectorize and apply it over the id variable:

```
        #make it a function 
        lagfun <- function(x){
          cbind(as.ts(x),lag(x))
        }

        y <- unlist(tapply(start,id,lagfun))
```

And this is where things get really ugly. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you put your time series in a `data.table`, you can accomplish this in a single line:

```
testDT[ , c("end", "switch") := 
          list( c(tail(start, -1), tail(end, 1)), cumsum(c(0, diff(amount) != 0)))
      , by=id]
```

---

Here it is broken down:

```
# create your data.table object 
library(data.table)
testDT <- data.table(test)


# Modify `end` by taking the lag of start and the final date from end. 
#   do this `by=id`
testDT[, end := c(tail(start, -1), tail(end, 1)), by=id]

# Count the ammount of times that each amount differs from the 
#  previous ammount value.  
# Start this vector at 0, and take the cummulative sum. 
#  also do this by id 
testDT[, switch := cumsum(c(0, diff(amount) != 0)), by=id]

# this is the final result. 
testDT
   id amount      start        end      noise switch
1:  3     24 2006-01-01 2009-12-09 -1.2070657      0
2:  3     48 2009-12-09 2010-01-01  0.2774292      1
3:  3     60 2010-01-01 2010-01-01  1.0844412      2
4:  5     84 2006-04-24 2009-12-09 -2.3456977      0
5:  5     96 2009-12-09 2009-12-09  0.4291247      1
6:  7    175 2009-05-01 2009-05-01  0.5060559      0
```

Comment: I should always start with data table. Thanks, you've made my day!

Comment: Well I'm glad I was able to make your day with such a short investment of time :)   data.table is mind bogglingly amazing, especially the `by=` which I find ends up saving countless minutes of coding time.

Comment: minutes? hours, days! There is a nice vignette for beginners like me [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf)

Comment: The FAQ (linked-to in the vignette) is also very helpful as are the help pages themselves (very well written and detailed)